# как в переменную записать нужное значение?

Tags: python, gui, pyqt, pyside2, pyside

Есть код:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
from ui import Ui_Form
import time
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)


Form = QtGui.QWidget()
ui = Ui_Form()
ui.setupUi(Form)
Form.show()
t = ""
#   функции
def but1():
    ui.lineEdit.setText(ui.lineEdit.text() + "1")
def but2():
    ui.lineEdit.setText(ui.lineEdit.text() + "2")   
def but3():
    ui.lineEdit.setText(ui.lineEdit.text() + "3")
def but4():
    ui.lineEdit.setText(ui.lineEdit.text() + "4")
def but5():
    ui.lineEdit.setText(ui.lineEdit.text() + "5")
def but6():
    ui.lineEdit.setText(ui.lineEdit.text() + "6")
def but7():
    ui.lineEdit.setText(ui.lineEdit.text() + "7")
def but8():
    ui.lineEdit.setText(ui.lineEdit.text() + "8")
def but9():
    ui.lineEdit.setText(ui.lineEdit.text() + "9")
def but_pl():
    ui.lineEdit.text() t
    ui.lineEdit.setText("")
    time.sleep(0.4)
    ui.lineEdit.setText(t)

    
#   кнопки
ui.but1.clicked.connect( but1 )
ui.but2.clicked.connect( but2 )
ui.but3.clicked.connect( but3 )
ui.but4.clicked.connect( but4 )
ui.but5.clicked.connect( but5 )
ui.but6.clicked.connect( but6 )
ui.but7.clicked.connect( but7 )
ui.but8.clicked.connect( but8 )
ui.but9.clicked.connect( but9 ) 
ui.but_pl.clicked.connect( but_pl )

#   основной код                        

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Сейчас внимание на функцию `def but_pl()`. 
Нужно чтобы значения с `lineEdit` записались в переменную, а затем `lineEdit` очистилась.
В данном случаи я вывожу значение из переменной обратно в `lineEdit`. 
Подскажите, как это реализовать?

Comment: Вообще ничего не понятно! Что вы подразумеваете под `записать в переменную` ? Это же вам не файл. чтобы записывать и не блокнот. В переменную можно `задать, установить` значение, через присваивание.

Comment: я имею в виду, что ари нажатии на кнопку, значение в lineEdit должно сохраниться в переменную.

Comment: Ну так реализуйте метод, при клике вызывайте и делаете, что угодно.

Comment: мне интересно можно ли, сохранить значение с lineEdit в переменную, чтобы затем использовать эти данные

Comment: И как это реализовать?

Comment: Ну в прочем у вас же уже привязана функция к кнопке и сделан клик. и я вижу, что вы для этого создали переменную `t` ну так и присваивайте к ней значение `t = ui.lineEdit.text()` в чем проблема то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы обновитесь и установите `PyQt5`,

```
pip install PyQt5
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

вы сможете проверить пример, который демонстрирует то, что вы хотите.

**main.py**

```
import sys
#import time

#from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from ui_form import Ui_Form                       # ui_form.py

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
ui = Ui_Form()
ui.setupUi(Form)
Form.show()

Form.t = ""                                        # + Form.

#   функции
def butClicked():
#    ui.lineEdit.setText(ui.lineEdit.text() + "1")
    v = Form.sender().text()
    ui.lineEdit.setText(ui.lineEdit.text() + v)

def but_save():
#    ui.lineEdit.text()                            #??? t
    Form.t = ui.lineEdit.text()
    ui.lineEdit.clear()                            # setText("")

#    time.sleep(0.4)
#    ui.lineEdit.setText(t)

def but_restore():
    ui.lineEdit.setText(Form.t)

#   кнопки
ui.but1.clicked.connect( butClicked )               # but1
ui.but2.clicked.connect( butClicked )
ui.but3.clicked.connect( butClicked )
ui.but4.clicked.connect( butClicked )
ui.but5.clicked.connect( butClicked )
ui.but6.clicked.connect( butClicked )
ui.but7.clicked.connect( butClicked )
ui.but8.clicked.connect( butClicked )
ui.but9.clicked.connect( butClicked ) 
ui.butSave.clicked.connect( but_save )
ui.butRestore.clicked.connect( but_restore )        # +++

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**ui_form.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'ui_form.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.12.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(274, 324)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(10)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.but1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.but1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.but1.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.but1.setObjectName("but1")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.but1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.but2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.but2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.but2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.but2.setObjectName("but2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.but2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.but4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.but4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.but4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.but4.setObjectName("but4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.but4, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.but7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.but7.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.but7.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.but7.setObjectName("but7")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.but7, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.but3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.but3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.but3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.but3.setObjectName("but3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.but3, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.but5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.but5.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.but5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.but5.setObjectName("but5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.but5, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.but6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.but6.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.but6.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.but6.setObjectName("but6")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.but6, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.but8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.but8.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.but8.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.but8.setObjectName("but8")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.but8, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.but9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.but9.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.but9.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.but9.setObjectName("but9")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.but9, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.butSave = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.butSave.setObjectName("butSave")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.butSave)
        self.butRestore = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.butRestore.setObjectName("butRestore")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.butRestore)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.but1.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        self.but2.setText(_translate("Form", "2"))
        self.but4.setText(_translate("Form", "4"))
        self.but7.setText(_translate("Form", "7"))
        self.but3.setText(_translate("Form", "3"))
        self.but5.setText(_translate("Form", "5"))
        self.but6.setText(_translate("Form", "6"))
        self.but8.setText(_translate("Form", "8"))
        self.but9.setText(_translate("Form", "9"))
        self.butSave.setText(_translate("Form", "Save"))
        self.butRestore.setText(_translate("Form", "Restore"))
```

---

**ui_form.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>274</width>
    <height>324</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
     <property name="spacing">
      <number>10</number>
     </property>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>16777215</width>
         <height>40</height>
        </size>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
       <item row="0" column="0">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="but1">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>50</width>
           <height>50</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>50</width>
           <height>50</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>1</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="1">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="but2">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>50</width>
           <height>50</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>50</width>
           <height>50</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>2</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="0">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="but4">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>50</width>
           <height>50</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>50</width>
           <height>50</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>4</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="3" column="0">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="but7">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>50</width>
           <height>50</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>50</width>
           <height>50</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>7</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="2">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="but3">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>50</width>
           <height>50</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>50</width>
           <height>50</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>3</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="1">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="but5">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>50</width>
           <height>50</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>50</width>
           <height>50</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>5</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="2">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="but6">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>50</width>
           <height>50</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>50</width>
           <height>50</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>6</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="3" column="1">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="but8">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>50</width>
           <height>50</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>50</width>
           <height>50</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>8</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="3" column="2">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="but9">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>50</width>
           <height>50</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>50</width>
           <height>50</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>9</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
     <item>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="butSave">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Save</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="butRestore">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Restore</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]